# JodaTime LocalTime to JSON - Actual Stack Overflow

Tags: java, json, stack-overflow, jodatime, fasterxml

I am trying to serialize Java objects to JSON. One of my Java objects has a JodaTime `LocalTime` object as one of its fields.

A fair number of my Java objects also have various fields that are `Collection`s that could be empty. I want to prevent the serialization of JSON that looks like this:

```
{id: 2348904, listOfThings: [], listOfStuff: [], nowASet: []}
```

In this scenario where those three `Collection`s are empty, I would rather see this JSON:

```
{id: 2348904}
```

The correct way to do such a thing is to configure the `ObjectMapper` with the following line of code:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

This works just fine...until I hit that Java object with the `LocalTime` inside of it. That's when I get an actual `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

It seems to be ping-ponging between `JodaDateSerializerBase.isEmpty()` and `JsonSerializer.isEmpty()`. I'm not sure how, though, because they don't call each other.

I managed to make a SSSSSSCCCCEEEE, or whatever the hell the acronym is, as follows:

```
package whatever.you.like;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass {
  public class JodaMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 34785437895L;

    public JodaMapper() {
      registerModule(new JodaModule());
    }

    public boolean getWriteDatesAsTimestamps() {
      return getSerializationConfig().isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    }

    public void setWriteDatesAsTimestamps(boolean state) {
      configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, state);
    }
  }

  private class Thing {
    private LocalTime localTime;

    public Thing() {}

    public void setLocalTime(LocalTime localTime) {
      this.localTime = localTime;
    }

    public LocalTime getLocalTime() {
      return localTime;
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void extendObjectMapperTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
    JodaMapper objectMapper = new JodaMapper();
    objectMapper.setWriteDatesAsTimestamps(false);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
    Thing thing = new Thing();
    LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(12389340L);
    thing.setLocalTime(localTime);
    System.out.println("Never manages to print this out: " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(thing));
  }

  @Test
  public void configureObjectMapperTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
    Thing thing = new Thing();
    LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(12389340L);
    thing.setLocalTime(localTime);
    System.out.println("Never manages to print this out: " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(thing));
  }
}
```

I tried both extending the `ObjectMapper` and configuring the `ObjectMapper`, and I get the same error each time.

Dependencies:

- JodaTime 2.6
- FasterXML's Jackson 2.5.0
- FasterXML's [Jackson-DataType-Joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) 2.5.0

Interestingly, you can find in that GitHub [a unit test](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/JodaSerializationTest.java) ("`testLocalDateSer()`") that claims to succeed using the `Include.NON_EMPTY` qualifier. I fail to see how it could possibly function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to

- FasterXML's Jackson 2.5.3
- FasterXML's  Jackson-DataType-Joda 2.5.3.

This works.

```
 @Test
  public void configureObjectMapperTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
//    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
    Thing thing = new Thing();
    LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(12389340L);
    thing.setLocalTime(localTime);
    System.out.println("Never manages to print this out: " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(thing));
  }
```

Comment: I upgraded to 2.5.3, and after several refreshes of my workspace to re-sync, this worked. I wonder if this is a helpful by-product of the fix for their [Bug #766](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/pull/766)? Also: The "WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS" line was indeed unnecessary, I had been experimenting with it set to "`true`" and forgot to remove the line.